# Calling method from another class, uiwebview and modal view issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview, modalviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I'm experiencing a few issues when trying to call a method from another class.  Here's my code

Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{

if ([url isFileURL]){
       RootViewController *theview = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
       [theview handleOpenURL:url];
       }
       return YES;
  }
```

RootViewController.h

```
 @interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
     IBOutlet UIWebView* mainwebView;
  }
- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView* mainWebView;
```

RootViewController.m

```
- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url{

NSLog(@"Method handleOpenURL completed")

[mainwebView setDelegate:self];
[self.mainwebView loadRequest:[[NSurLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];



[self performSelector:@selector(handleIt) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
}

- (void)handleIt{
docView *docController = [[docView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:docController animated:YES];
}
```

So, basically I'm trying to update a UIWebView and then present a modal view controller once the appdelegate calls handleOpenURL.  The problem is that both of these things (updating webview and presenting view controller) refuse to work in the method handleOpenURL.  They work perfectly fine in viewdidload, which makes me think it has something to do with the method being called from appdelegate.

The webview simply refuses to respond when accessed from the handleOpenURL method, and when I present the modal view controller I get the error

```
 Warning: Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

But, again the modalview works fine when presented from viewdidload (using the time delay selector)

An explanation to why this is happening or a workaround would be great, thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it have something to do with using 'self' when I'm calling the method from app delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `#import "docView.h"` in your `RootViewController.m`.

```
 Warning: Attempt to present ... whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

The warning states the view is not recognized, meaning you don't have access to the class properly, if it's not importing, then you didn't set up the code in `docView.m` properly.

*If that doesn't work, than i need more info to help solve your problem.*

---

***Edit for Clarification:***

- The app-delegate is called at the start and when pointed to, not
  constantly.
- You should call it from when the modal view loads, a method
  pointer([self myFunctionNameHere];) would work just fine.
- So it's that your not accessing the app-delegate properly.
- I don't think you should even be calling it from the app-delegate,
  call it from your .m.

### Calling it from your main(.m) file would solve everything.

Comment: So, my docView.h is imported correctly, I know this because when I present the modal from rootviewcontroller's viewdidload it works fine.  The problem is when I try to present the modal using a method called by my appdelegate.